# How do I sort a merged list into ascending order?

Tags: sorting, haskell

```
merge :: [a] -> [a] -> [a]

 merge xs     []     = xs
 merge []     ys     = ys
 merge (x:xs) (y:ys) = x : y : merge xs ys
```

I have got this working but now I need to sort them in ascending order.

Comment: And the source lists are already in ascending order?

Comment: If all you know about your list is that it was created by your `merge` function, the best you can do is to just sort the list. If you also know that the two initial lists were sorted and of the same size, you can "unmerge" the list to get the two original lists back and then merge them again with another function that maintains the sortedness.

Answer (score 4):

You just need to compare `x` and `y` and decide which to add to the result first. Note that you only add *one* at a time; the next element after `x` might still come before `y`.

Note you need the `Ord` constraint to ensure that `<=` is defined for `a`.

```
merge :: Ord a => [a] -> [a] -> [a]
merge xs [] = xs
merge [] ys = ys
merge xs@(x:xs') ys@(y:ys') | x <= y = x : merge xs' ys
                            | otherwise = y : merge xs ys'
```